# How can I read the value from mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Following is a value I am seeing in one of my fields in mysql for wordpress database

> **a:2:{i:0;i:31;i:1;i:23;}**

What is this format? How can I get the valued of alternate I using PHP ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a [`serialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)'d variable, you can use [`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to convert back to the appropriate datatype - in this case an Array with Integer indexes and values.

For WordPress there is a function called [`maybe_unserialize()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) which is useful for database values if you aren't sure if it has been serialized or not.

Answer (score 2):

its in `serialize` form you can use `unserialize()` php function

Answer (score 1):

That's serialized data, the 'a' means array and the 2 represents two child parts of that array.

What I would recommend though rather than pulling information out via custom queries is to use Wordpress' inbuilt functions (get_posts, get_user_meta etc) which will safely retrieve the data and you can do so much more with it. Plus it's built for extension meaning you're not reinventing the wheel each time